# vue-router : router-link not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to use vue-router and `router-link`. When I click on the link, the URL updates correctly, but nothing is loaded into `<router-view></router-view>`. I'm guessing this has something to do with using the unpkg CDNs rather than building this with vue-CLI? I'm not really sure why this isn't working.

**index.html**

```
....

<body>

    ....

    <nav id="app">
        <li><router-link to="/hello">Hello</router-link></li>
    <nav>

    <!--view-->
    <router-view></router-view>

    ....
    <!--vue.js-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

    <!--router-->
    <script src="js/router.js"></script>
</body>
```

**router.js**

```
const Hello = { template: '<div>test</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/hello', component: Hello }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

I've tried removing the `<li> </li>` around the `router-link`, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I was getting this issue due to some hacky code in the vue-material library. Not to be confused with vuetify. https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1977

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `const app = new Vue({})`, this creates a new **vue instance**

then you are using `$mount()` which takes in an element selector as an argument.

What `$mount()` does is, it manually mounts the Vue instance to the associated DOM element that you pass as the argument

In your code, only the `nav` element has the id of `app` which means only the `nav` element is mounted to your Vue instance not the `router-view` which is outside of the `nav` element.

That is why your answer of adding a wrapper with an id of `app` works because now the `router-view` is also associated with the Vue instance.

You can refer to:

[vm.$mount()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) , [Vue instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)

Answer (score 1):

It works when I attach the `app` id to a wrapper `<div>` around everything, like this:

```
....

    <div id="app">

        <nav>
            <li><router-link to="/hello">Hello</router-link></li>
        <nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Instead give to body tag like this <body id='app'>

Comment: Hi, Please don't give `body` id `app`. You will get this error: `[Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead.`

Answer (score 1):

In my case router-link is **not working because i have sidebar outside of `<div id="app"></div>`**

So the **moral of the story is we have to put all vue related element or stuff in the div which we have used for mounting in `app.js`**

So Structure of html Should be as Below:

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id="app">
  <aside>
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <li><router-link to="/users">Users</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link to="/home">Home</router-link></li>
  </aside>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <event-hub></event-hub>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearing my browser history helped me

Answer (score 0):

Just add key to

```
<router-view id="view" :key ='$route.params.id || $route.params'
```

or when pass param is id and users click also on # links so its not refresh

```
<router-view id="view" :key ='$route.params.id || $route.params'
```